# Wrong post on submit

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP page (page.php) that I am using to post data into my database. I am using the form method post to send the data to my database. Inside the `<form>` I have a second `<form>` which I use to upload an image.

But when I click on `Upload` the outer `<form>` will posted: `action="./submit.php"`.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Here is my script:

**page.php**

```
<form name="reaction" method="post" action="./submit.php">
    //multiple textboxes

    //upload script 

    <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="page.php">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr><td><input type="file" name="image" value="Choose file"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><br /><input name="Submit" class="btn2" type="submit" value="Upload"></td></tr>
        </table> 
    </form>

<button type="submit">Post page</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Nested forms aren’t valid HTML; you need to restructure somehow. The [`form` attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute) would make that easy, but it isn’t supported by IE 11/Edge.

Comment: But I need to post the image. If this is not valid, than what is a valid solution?

Comment: [`formaction` and `formenctype`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-submit-attributes) if you don’t need IE 9 support; CSS that moves the outer form’s button around otherwise.

Comment: You need to make them two separate forms. One to upload the textboxes, the other for the image.

Comment: Or you could use AJAX to do the submission, then you can write Javascript that uploads all the form fields or just the image depending on which button you click on.

Answer (score 0):

well Ryan is right, you can't have a `<form>` inside a `<form>` my suggestion is change the html stucture or make it into one `<form>` with one action and maybe you can split the function inside `submit.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have nested form like this in HTML.Follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) instruction to better undrestanding about form handling in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two submit buttons in one form, they can each have a different `formaction` to specify where to submit.

```
<form name="reaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //multiple textboxes

    //upload script 

    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr><td><input type="file" name="image" value="Choose file"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><br /><input name="Submit" class="btn2" type="submit" value="Upload" formaction="page.php"></td></tr>
    </table> 

<button type="submit" formaction="submit.php">Post page</button>
</form>
```

Both buttons will submit all the form fields, but the two scripts can simply ignore the fields that they don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendations:**

- Step 1: separate each form
- Step 2: give each form an id
- Step 3: use [jquery's $.ajax()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) to publish the forms to their respective targets URLs

**Example of Ajax call:**

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            //data: return data from server
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //if fails      
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});
```

*Code from [hog](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/) I was lazy to write one*